# 'Windows.h: No such file or directory" error when changing Platform Toolset to v140_xp

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, windows-xp

I tried to compile an application for Windows XP; the normal executable gives the error:

> "... is not a valid Win32 application."

I read that I could create an XP-compatible executable by changing the Platform Toolset to `Visual Studio 2015 - Windows XP (v140_xp)`, but when I do that and then try to compile it gives me the following errors:

> Cannot open include file: 'Windows.h': No such file or directory
>
> Could not find WindowsSdkDir_71A variable from registry. TargetFrameWorkVersion or Platform toolset may be set to an invalid version number.

How can I compile with this toolset version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After setting the Platform Toolset to `Visual Studio 2015 - Windows XP (v140_xp)`, you close VS 2015 and reopen your project. It will automatically give a pop up that will tell you to install some files for supporting Windows XP projects.

Comment: When I reloaded the solution after changing the toolset, it said "MyProject (unavailable)" in the project explorer. Right-clicking and choosing "Install Missing Feature(s)" will initiate the support update.

Comment: I have the same problem with missing windows.h when using v140_xp and nothing suggested here works.